# Connecting a hose to a 3/8 compression fitting

Tags: plumbing

I have a dog waterer that has a female garden hose connection. I would like to take a tee off my 3/8 compression fitting above my cut off valve under the sink to connect to this. Any suggestions on the best route to go? I would prefer to stick with a short braided hose like you would use for a toilet to make the run... But I have no idea how to take a compression fitting to a garden hose.

Comment: Your local plumbing store will have adapters, most hose bibs are 3/4”, you won’t need that at all feeding a 3/8 from under the sink by adding a shutoff valve with 2 ports or another method of adding a T would make sense to me.

Comment: @EdBeal, you should probably turn that into an Answer.

Comment: it sounds like the dog waterer is designed to go outside ... it is probably not guaranteed to be leakproof ... you may wish to rethink using it indoors if you plan to have it connected to a water supply at all times

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what your valves under your sink look like , I would suggest possibly a new valve with 2 ports or the addition of a T  on a 3/8 fitting then you could find a pre made hose like you want for a Refrigerator, this can feed your waterer.

I would want an independent shut off incase of problems, 
my plumbing speciality store could set up all the parts needed and suggest things like an extra valve just in case by using a photo of your existing under sink set up. They may cost a few dollars more but 1 trip ends up saving time and frustration in the long run compared to the big box stores , the big box may have what you need but getting the correct help sometimes it tough.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Adding a 3/8 T is exactly what I was thinking. I'm just not sure about connecting the compression fitting to the hose bib. Nothing over seen makes sense for going from a female 3/8 compression fitting to a hose bib, even going through several steps.

Comment: I mis understood , I thought the connection to the waterer was 3/8 ok I understand it Is a hose fitting , this may take 2 reducers to go from the 3/4 down to a 3/8 so a standard 3/8 hose could be used but my advice to use a plumbing speciality store would be the same they have more off the wall stuff than a big box store.

Answer (score 0):

For the life of me I couldn't remember where I'd seen that connection, and the local Lowe's guy wasn't helpful. 3/8 compression to female hose bib is common in dishwasher installations, which wasn't in the same location as any of the other brass parts.

Answer (score 0):

I know some may respond that this is not an answer to the question but sometimes it is necessary to shed light on why the question may be trying to solve the wrong thing.

I second the comment from @jsotola. The hose fitting connection should make it obvious that the dog watering unit is made for use outdoors. You do not want to hard connect the watering unit indoors because a feisty dog could easily overturn the unit and you may return one day to a flooded house.

If you need an indoor unit get one of the types that recirculates a limited supply of water to keep it fresh and then refill it as needed. In the case of these the water spillage in an overturn is much much less.

Answer (score 0):

How did this turn out for you? I am madman too and putting an auto water bowl inside, it has to have power to work so I have a dead man switch to shut power off.  If I don't fail on the plumbing I should be ok.

Looks like the rule is I have to answer this so, I'd go with some kind of Compression Fitting, one side smooth pipe other side a thread, and then thread adaptors till you get to hose size.  2 years too late and idiot answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/149425)

Comment: nevermind, just gonna delete my account, just wanted to see how it went.  If he still needs help after 2 years I just went through this I can help him. But ya thanks, good job sentry gotta keep this place safe!

Comment: Welcome to DiY! The idea here is that you offer your solution straight away, these boxes are labeled 'answer' for that reason. If you do have an idea on how to tackle this, feel free to add this with an [edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/254934/edit) :)